# Test standalone JS file in Jasmine/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a standalone javascript file, cacheBustingInterceptor.js in a node.js app. It is a service in a factory pattern that is invoked by the app.js when the app holds.

```
/** 
* Intercept the http request 
* If the config.url is from upload or templates and is a html file
* append the cacheBusting Param
* If the template url has query param exisitng
* append &_dt=epochtime else append ?_dt=epochtime
*/
var cacheBustingInterceptor = {
CacheBustingService: CacheBustingServiceFactory
};

function CacheBustingServiceFactory() {
function CacheBustingService() {}

var possibleHtmlPaths = ['templates', 'upload'];
CacheBustingService.prototype.appendCacheBustingParam = function(templateUrl) {
    for (var index = 0; index != possibleHtmlPaths.length; index++) {

        // check if the url has is .html and from upload and templates
        var addCacheBusting = templateUrl.indexOf(possibleHtmlPaths[index]) != - 1 && 
            templateUrl.indexOf('.html') != - 1;
        var hasQueryParams = templateUrl.indexOf('?') != -1;

        if (addCacheBusting) {
            if (hasQueryParams) {
                return templateUrl + window.appendCacheBustingParam;
            } else {
                return templateUrl + window.cacheBustingParam;
            }
        } 
    }
    return templateUrl;
};

CacheBustingService.prototype.interceptRequest = function() {
    var _this = this;
    var cacheBuster = {
        request: function (config) {
            config.url = _this.appendCacheBustingParam(config.url);
            return config;
        }
    }
    return cacheBuster;
}

return CacheBustingService;
```

}

the way we invoke this is by adding a injector to the app.js in the config and push the factory to the configs.

like so,

```
   app. config([''$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('templateCacheBustingInjector');

  app.factory('templateCacheBustingInjector', ['$injector', function 
    ($injector) {
    var CacheBustingService = 
         $injector.invoke(cacheBustingInterceptor.CacheBustingService);
         var cacheBustingService = new CacheBustingService();

    return cacheBustingService.interceptRequest();
  }]);
```

Now this all works fine but I want to unit test the method 'appendCacheBustingParam' in the cacheBustingInterceptor.js and running out of ideas to invoke it from the jasmine unit test

Things tired:
1. invoking the way I invoked in the app.js, but I get service injection error or provider error
2. load the js file using require but require is not supported and I tried using browsify, however, that too doesnot help.

```
  require('../main/webapp/media/scripts/cacheBustingInterceptor.js'); 

  fdescribe('Cache Busting Service', function() {
      var cacheBustingService;
       var $injector;

beforeEach((inject(function (_$injector_) {
    $injector = _$injector_;
   $injector.get(cacheBustingInterceptor.CacheBustingService);
    // var CacheBustingService = $injector.invoke(cacheBustingInterceptor.CacheBustingService);
})));

it('Test appendCacheBustingParam', function() {
    cacheBustingService = new CacheBustingService();
    spyOn(cacheBustingService.prototype, 'appendCacheBustingParam');
    expect(cacheBustingService.prototype).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});

Comment: Since CacheBustingService is used with AngularJS any way, it would make sense to write it as a provider. You wouldn't have such problems with testing if you were using DI as always. Also, the answer already contains valid points about this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a terminology problem here when you say "stand alone".

*Unit* tests test an *isolated* unit of code.

*Intergration* tests test the interaction *between* isolated units.

A *unit* test for your method might be something like

```
const mock = {}; // fill with appropriate properties
const result = CacheBustingService
  .prototype
  .appendCacheBustingParam
  .call(mock, someURL);

expect(result).toBe(expectedResult);
```

A unit test should not require wiring up a service. Unit tests should generally be runnable in node, from the command line, ideally without running even so much as `npm install` because you've stubbed everything out. Your unit tests should run subsecond. Preferably for the entire suite, but this may not be possible depending on codebase size.

What it sounds like you want is an *integration* test: does creating the service actually wire up everything appropriately?

In the case of integration tests, it totally makes sense to *actually* construct the service to find out, meaning running it in a browser with e.g. karma and the actual dependencies (not as a standalone file). Integration tests can be slower/run less often.

### One final note

Your method is not very amenable to automated testing, because it references globals and does so via window:

```
        if (hasQueryParams) {
            return templateUrl + window.appendCacheBustingParam;
        } else {
            return templateUrl + window.cacheBustingParam;
        }
```

Make those parameters to the method instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think I should have rephrased my question better, the problem is I am not able to inject the service in the test folder. So if I do, 

   const result = CacheBustingService
     .prototype
     .appendCacheBustingParam
     .call(mock, someURL);

I will get CacheBustingService -> angular providerInjection error.

Comment: @Maria again, are you testing the *app*, end to end, or just this service? If it's the former, then you should be writing tests in e.g. selenium to actually model user interaction with your frontend hitting your backend and onwards. If it's the latter, then just import it, stub out collaborators, and call it with a mock. Taking the middle road here is both not very helpful and (as you've discovered) quite difficult.